# Calculating damage on a crit with an item's encounter power?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

If I crit. while using a Frostbrand's close blast encounter power, do I add in the "crit per plus" of d8 as well? Even though it wasn't used as a melee attack?

Answer (score 3):

#### By RAW, probably not.

The encounter power for a **Frost Brand Weapon** does not include the ***Weapon*** or ***Implement*** keywords.  This will prevent a lot of feats and abilities from affecting this attack.  I don't think it is RAW to allow the critical bonus damage from Frost Brand Weapons when using its attack power.  Generally you only include weapon/implement bonuses & properties in an attack if the attack includes the appropriate keyword.

As a DM I'd probably allow it though (since the weapon is clearly being used in the attack despite the lack of keywords - I still wouldn't allow its properties to be used for the normal attack and damage bonuses though).

Comment: I'm sure this must come up with many items? I'm curious what the RAW is, and cannot find it.

Comment: @DavidIgoe As Nick explained, if a power does not have the *Weapon* keyword, it does not get **any** bonuses from your weapon's enchantment, including attack, damage, and critical damage.

Comment: Well, if the power includes the implement keyword and you can use the weapon as an implement then it gets the bonuses too (that's why I discussed both keywords).